# font-size on 2K and higher resolution devices

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, font-size

I have a screen with resolution `1680 x 1050`.

I work as a web developer and while building websites, we use `font-sizes` that are easily readable on laptops with resolutions ranging between `1366 x 768` to `1920 x 1080`.

While using **Chrome developer tools**, I chose **Amazon Kindle Fire HDX** which has resolution of `2560 x 1600`. On this device (which chrome is simulating), the font-size renders very small due to high-res. I tried many font-size units such as `vw, vh, %` so that the font-size appears same on all resolutions but failed.

I even opened StackOverflow using Chrom Dev Tool and saw the font-size appearing to be too small. I don't know if the font size that appears on the real Kindle HDX is the same as what I'm seeing on Kindle HDX that chrome is simulating and I don't have a real 2K res device to test my websites as well. How to counter this issue? I want my websites to be readable on all resolutions.

Comment: I don't have a Kindle either, but I can see what you mean, with the emulators. Let's hope Chrome has got it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your font sizes are in relative units then you are likely just fine.

I think what you are seeing in Chrome Dev Tools is the "Zoom to fit" feature that will zoom the page of the targeted device to fit ***your browser window***. Uncheck "Zoom to fit" and I think you will see the text is legible. And take notice that the ruler values will change to be more accurate representation as well.

*You can see in this screenshot that the rulers indicate that the device simulation is being rendered at 1600px wide even though this screenshot was definitely not taken at 1600px wide. It was zoomed to fit my window.*
[image: Screenshot of Chrome Dev Tools Zoom to Fit]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use em as the unit for fonts to make it more cross-browser/device compatible. em should work off the browser's own built-in font sizes to make things more readable as well as the browser's zoom settings.

Also, you may want to try out various CSS frameworks that may try to handle more consistent cross-browser/device consistency to keep fonts at more relative sizes according to device/dpi settings. (Unfortunately, I haven't experience in this scenario, but should be a good place to start your research).